# If you need anyone to talk about this matter, just remember that I'm always here

Tags: prepositions

Here's a context.

> If you need anyone to talk about this matter, just remember that I'm always here.

Here, what if I add '***with'*** right after matter?

> If you need anyone to talk about this matter ***with***, just remember that I'm always here.

I think this is more comfortable to use.

Comment: First off, you don't really have a question.  Secondly, the more idiomatic phrase is: "*If you need to talk, I'm here for you.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using *with* is better because it implies the important speech between two people. In your first example, it is not really clear you would be talking (could be anyone).

But you second example does not seem natural as written, because *with* is related to *talk*, not *about this matter*. So it would be better to say:

> If you need anyone to talk **with** about this matter, just remember that I'm always here.

You could also use *talk to*, though that would be more impersonal.